# how to replace all occurrences of // (double slash) in a string with dot sign in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace

I need to replace all occurrences of // with . in a string, but the solution I have now replaces each slash with "."

So Folder//file//name becomes **Folder..file..name**

It's a Node.js app and it didn't like replaceAll..

**Code**:

```
filename = filename.replace(/\//g, ".");
```

Comment: Add another escaped forward slash `\/` to ur regular expression: `.replace(/\/\//g, '.');`

Comment: have you tried filename.replace(/\/\//g,".")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the experession:

```js
const path = 'Folder//file//name';

console.log(path.replace(/(\/\/)/gm, "."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
filename.replace(/\/\//g, ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = filename.replace(/\//g, ".");
```

This code replaces all one `/`s with `.`
but if you want to replace double slashes `//` with one dot `.`, you should use:

```
filename = filename.replace(/\/\//g, ".");
```